# Using EF core power tools, Need Update model and table to add Column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net WebAPI and I created models by EF core power tools.
So, there is a Context file in Model folder.

Actually, I wanna add column in existing table, so I need to change the model as well. How can I do that?  In EF Core tools, there is no option to update the model and table. I already added the column in the database.

Comment: Run the tool again?

Answer (score 2):

You can use to reload the model

[image]

you can run the tool again.
you can not see all tables in your DB.

[image]

Your tables have to has a primary key (because of EF-core use only that tables have a primary key)

[image]